# Why in formula of power of periodic signal is $2N+1$?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, periodic

Where does $1$ come from, like from $-N$ to $N$ is $2N$ so why is $2N+1$?

Comment: -N to -1 is N, 1 to N is N, then you need to count the 0 index so all together it’s 2N+1. Just choose an N, write the numbers -N to N down, and count how many you have.

Comment: yes  i got the idea thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't $-N$ to $N$ $2N+1$ index in total (you probably missed the 0 here)

$$ P = \lim_{N\to\infty} {\frac{1}{2N+1} \sum_{n=-N}^N} \lvert x[n] \rvert^2 $$